# Mongoose + NodeJS - Looping through documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have two collection - Call them main and sub. My main collection looks like below,

```
{
  "_id" : "xxxxx",
  "subId" : "1234"
}
```

And my sub looks something like,

```
{
  "_id" : "1234",
  "name" : "somename"
}
```

And I write a query like -

```
Main.find({_id : { $in : ids }},function(err, results){
  //Do something here
});
```

Now, I want my final result as,

```
{
  "_id" : "xxxx",
  "subName" : "somename"
}
```

How do I iterate in the documents and achieve the desired result. i am fairly new to MEAN stack. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reference and [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) schemas like these:

```
var mainSchema = Schema({
  _id: Number,
  subId: Number,
  name: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Sub' }]
});

var subSchema = Schema({
  _id: Number,
  name: String,
});

var Main  = mongoose.model('Main', mainSchema);
var Sub = mongoose.model('Sub', subSchema);
```

Now you can "populate" the query with the subdocuments from `Sub` collection:

```
Main.find({_id : { $in : ids }}).populate('name').exec(function(err, results){
  //Do something here
});
```

Comment: Using a schemas with mongo (via mongoose) is not a requirement of using mongo

Comment: I edited the answer with "could" instead "have to".

Comment: thanks a lot. this helps.